# How to make a div onload function?

Tags: javascript

I want to load an HTML page as a div inside my webpage by removing its HTML and body tags. But the HTML page has a `<body onload=" ... " >` , I need this function to continue working. Seems `<div onload=" ... " >` is not working.  How can I insert this onload function into my website's body (on this page only) without directly editing my original website code (php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the contents of the page into your div

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#containing-div").load("[url of page with onload function]");
});
```

the code above goes in the page that contains the div.  the page with the onload function doesn't get changed.

Answer (score 6):

Have you used jQuery before?  If so, just get the id of your div (let's say "SomeDiv") and then use the "ready" method like this:

```
$("#SomeDiv").ready(
function(){
     //do stuff
    });
```

Comment: This Works!, This is the exact answer Im waiting for

Comment: It worked for me too! Thanks! It's also worth to know this code should be on the first level of javascript code, as `$(document).ready()`. And this code is not the same as `document.getElementById("SomeDiv").onload = ...` , because this code will throw an error, since the element doesn't exist for javascript until all HTML is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an additional Javascript tag at the end of the loaded page (once inserted inside the div) which will executing as soon as it's loaded. Like this:

```
<div>
    Insert the inner html content of that pages here and add this script at the bottom and add the onload function of the original html to this script.
    <script type="javascript">
       alert("hello world");
    </script>
</div>
```

Just remember to have the javascript available to your page. What I mean is that if the javascript function called which is called inside `onload="..."` is defined in the `<head>` of the loading html document and you're throwing the `<head>` out then this won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Not the best but one way is to check the div periodically if it's loaded:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
if ($('.mydiv') && $('.mydiv').width() > 0) {
// write your logic here
clearInterval(myInterval);
    } 
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to add the onload event on a div, you cannot, but you can add onkeydown and trigger the onkeydown event on document load.

```
<div onkeydown="setCss();"></div>

$(function () {
    $(".ccsdvCotentPS").trigger("onkeydown");
});
```