# How to change background color randomly in HTML with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

this web page changes the backgrounder color randomly. i am having trouble to do the same thing with "#title" ,but the color stays the same.

please help

Thank you

JavaScript code:

```
function setbackground()
{
    window.setTimeout( "setbackground()", 80); //  milliseconds delay

    var index = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);

    var ColorValue = "FFFFFF"; // default color - white (index = 0)

    if(index == 1)
        ColorValue = "66FF33"; 
    if(index == 2)
        ColorValue = "FF0000"; 
    if(index == 3)
        ColorValue = "FF00FF"; 
    if(index == 4)
        ColorValue = "0000FF"; 
    if(index == 5)
        ColorValue = "00FFFF"; 
    if(index == 6)
        ColorValue = "FFFF00"; 
    if(index == 7)
       ColorValue = "CC66FF"; 
    if(index == 8)
        ColorValue = "3366FF"; 
   if(index == 9)
        ColorValue = "CCCCCC"; 

   document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#" + ColorValue;

}

function setbackgroundTitle()
{
    window.setTimeout( "setbackgroundTitle()", 600); //  milliseconds delay

    var index = Math.round(Math.random() * 4);

    var ColorValue = "FFFFFF"; // default color - white (index = 0)

    if(index == 1)
        ColorValue = "66FF33"; 
    if(index == 2)
        ColorValue = "FF0000"; 
    if(index == 3)
        ColorValue = "FF00FF"; 
    if(index == 4)
        ColorValue = "0000FF"; 


    document.getElementById("title")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#" + ColorValue;

}
```

CSS code:

```
#title{
    background-color:#11f22f;
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    margin:25px auto 0 auto;
    -moz-border-radius:25px;
    -webkit-border-radius:25px;
}
```

html Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>HomeWork</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="crazy.js"> </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HomeWork2.css" />

    </head>
    <body>

    <body onload="setbackground();">
        <div id="title" onload="setbackgroundTitle();"> hjhjhkj dfvdfsv dfgvkdfsk dfs</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the future, consider using anonymous functions as opposed to strings for `setTimeout`. `setTimeout(function(){setbackgroundTitle()}, 600);` will suffice.

Comment: __General code tip:__ if you have several if statements like this they will all be run each time, even if index is 1. Use a switch statement instead. Or in this case, a even better solution is to store all the color values in an array, and use myColorArray[index] to get your value.

Comment: this is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455485/how-change-background-color-of-html-elements-with-javascript-in-a-certain-time-p/25455719#25455719

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, copy paste error: instead `document.getElementById("title")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#" + ColorValue;` there should be `document.getElementById("title").style.backgroundColor = "#" + ColorValue;`
According with that [How to make a div onload function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500185/how-to-make-a-div-onload-function)  doesn't work.
I've put everything to setbackground() and it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

try so:

```
document.getElementById("title").style.backgroundColor = "#" + ColorValue;
```

Comment: no change , maybe the problem is in the html file. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If that is homework, please tag your question as homework.

Else, jQuery would make your life as simple as:

```
$("body").css("background", "#456789");
```

or

```
$("h1").css("background", "#456789");
```

Comment: It's not a tagged jQuery too dude :)

Comment: Not tagged jQuery does not mean I should not suggest a simple solution to a question. As of today, I see no point to use pure Javascript in 95% of the cases (homework is a valid reason though, to learn the language :)

Comment: Guys in the jQuery Project certainly WOULD see the point. Chill out man.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the DOM wasn't loaded when the script was running.

Correct your function to this, you are assuming the output of `document.getElementById("title")` as an array, but its not.

```
document.getElementById("title").style.backgroundColor = "#" + ColorValue;
```

And call it on the onload event, to ensure the DOM is loaded properly when the script runs

```
window.onload = function() {
 setbackgroundTitle();
};
```